# Apply mllib function over groups in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I would like to apply the AUC function from pyspark.ml.evaluation to groups within a pyspark dataframe.

I've a spark table selected from a databse, with my score and observed columns:

```
    predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda = spark.table('sda_model').filter((col('region_id') == region_id) &  (col('weekend_day') == to_date(lit(execParams['date']), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))).select( 
        col('attributed_units_sold').cast('double').alias('attributed_units_sold')
        ,col('sdar_score').cast('double').alias('sdar_score')
        ,col('marketplace_id').cast('double').alias('marketplace_id')
    )

evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="attributed_units_sold", rawPredictionCol="sdar_score")
```

I can extract single numbers by applying the functions below to the whole dataframe

```
     auc_sda = evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda, {evaluator.metricName: "areaUnderROC"})
     aupr_sda = evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda, {evaluator.metricName: "areaUnderPR"})
```

But cannot find a way to apply the functions over the marketplace_id column.

The below returns an  error

```
     predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda=  predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda.withColumn("auc", predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda.groupBy("marketplace_id").apply(evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda, {evaluator.metricName: "areaUnderROC"})))
     predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda=  predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda.withColumn("aupr", predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda.groupBy("marketplace_id").apply(evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndSprScoreLabels_sda, {evaluator.metricName: "areaUnderPR"})) )

class 'ValueError'>: Invalid udf: the udf argument must be a pandas_udf of type GROUPED_MAP
```

I should note I am restricted to using pyspark.ml.

Answer (score 0):

[BinaryClassificationEvaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator.html) doesn't support groups. In order to use it you need to filter one group at a time before applying the evaluator.

However, if you don't want to perform several computations [Pandas UDFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) are a good candidate. They are supported in `df.groupby().agg()` expressions and allow you to define complex aggregation functions in Python over Pandas DataFrames. You can't use [BinaryClassificationEvaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator.html) over the grouped data. It's not a PySpark DataFrame. In your case you might want to use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for computing the metrics over the Pandas Series.

Here is a code example illustrating the second approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import function as F, types as T
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


@F.udf(T.FloatType())
def get_p1(v):
    return float(v.values[1])

@F.pandas_udf('float')
def agg_func1(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series) -> float:
    return roc_auc_score(s1, s2)

@F.pandas_udf('float')
def agg_func2(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series) -> float:
    pass


(
    df
    .withColumn('p1', get_p1(F.col('raw')))
    .groupby('group')
    .agg(
        agg_func1(df['label'], df['p1']).alias('metric1'),
        agg_func2(df['label'], df['p1']).alias('metric2'),
     )
    .show()
)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm restricted to using base pyspark, have updated the original question.